# iterate through a formgroup that has a formarray of a formgroup of control angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, reactive

Hello am having some issues iterating the following form in my template
Am using the reactive form, to render the form. Also made use of the form builder as service to create the form.
I have a form group that a nested formArray
In my template, I have edit and a read mode view

In my class component I have the following codes :

```
public myFormGroup: FormGroup;
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myFormGroup = this.createStudentGradeForm();
  }

  public get studentGradesLevel(): FormArray {
    return this.myFormGroup.get('studentGradesLevels') as FormArray;
  }

  public createStudentGradeForm(): FormGroup {
   return this.formBuilder.group({
      studentGradesLevels : this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          studentGradeOne: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              label: this.formBuilder.control('4 - 6 years standard'),
              value: this.formBuilder.control(0),
            }),
          ]),
          studentGradeTwo: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              label: this.formBuilder.control('7 - 10 years standard'),
              value: this.formBuilder.control(0),
            }),
          ])
        }),
      ]),
    });
}
```

In my template, I have the following

```
  <div [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <div formArrayName="studentGradesLevel">
     <div *ngFor="let studentGradesLevelof studentGradesLevels['controls']; let i = index; let last = last" id="{{ i }}">
              <ng-container
                    *ngTemplateOutlet="(formService.readonly$ | async) ? readOnlyTemplate : editFormTemplate; context: {  studentGradesLevel: studentGradesLevel['controls']  } " >
</ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<ng-template #readOnlyTemplate let-studentGradesLevel="studentGradesLevel">
  <div *ngFor="let level of studentGradesLevel" class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-6">
        {{ level.get('label')?.value }}
    </label>
    <div>
      {{ level.get('value')?.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #editFormTemplate let-studentGradesLevel="studentGradesLevel">
  <div *ngFor="let level of studentGradesLevel"  class="form-group row">
    <ng-container [formGroup]="level">
        <p>
           {{ level.get('label')?.value }}
        </p>
        <ng-container>
            <input [formControl]="level.get('value')" />
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Json structure

```
studentGradesLevels = {
studentGradeOne:{
[{ value '' , label: ''}]
},
studentGradeTwo:{
[{ value '' , label: ''}]
},
studentGradeThree:{
[{ value '' , label: ''}]
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? it's not rendering in html?

Comment: @Chellappan வ yes am not able to render it properly, am getting sometimes errors likes [objects][objects] or while to try to get final result sometimes i got error like controls not defined , am being struggling with the rendering for a while, i think am not reading the path properly that why am lost

Comment: If possible can you share the json structure of your form?

Comment: @Chellappan வ thank you for your help i have posted json structure above

Comment: It's not valid object, I am confused can you please share correct one